# Cross reference to counter in section title

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I am trying to use a custom counter in Latex in order to auto number Use Cases in section titles (eg. `\section{UC <counter>: use case title}`). I also want a `\usecaseref` command to substitute a reference by the full use case name: *UCx: use case title*.

This is what I got so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{UCcounter}

\newcommand{\usecaseprint}[1]{UC \arabic{UCcounter}: #1}

\newcommand{\usecaseincrease}{\refstepcounter{UCcounter}}

\newcommand{\usecaseref}[1]{\emph{\nameref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\usecaseincrease
\section{\usecaseprint{First Use Case Name}\label{sec:first}}

    This is the forwards reference: \usecaseref{sec:second}.

\usecaseincrease
\section{\usecaseprint{Second Use Case Name} \label{sec:second} }

    This is the backwards reference: \usecaseref{sec:first}

\end{document}
```

This however produces the following:

[image]

As you can see, when calling the `\nameref` command, it uses the current value of the `UCcounter` instead of the value of the counter in the section title.

I already tried to replace the `\newcommand` occurences with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: If you look in the `.aux` file, you'll see that the section title reported in it is `\usecaseprint {First Use Case Name}` which will then use the current value for the counter. Do those section titles contain other things than `\usecaseprint{...}`?

Comment: As egreg stated: The problem is, that `\usecaseprint{}` is written unexpanded to the `.aux` file, so it will call the counter value at its current value, not at the moment, the statement was written to the file. The source of the problem is inside the `label` command.

Comment: @egreg: I am using the solution posted by "latex", but I want to use Umlaute in my titles. Even if I am writing `{\"a}`, the command `\immediate\write1{}` writes `ä` into .aux and I get the error `Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: ... not set up for use with LaTeX ...` What can I do?

Comment: @Make42 That's a job for `\protected@write`

Comment: @egreg: I tried that but that does not yet work. I put `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` around the entire command. I don't get errors anymore, but also nothing into the aux-file. In a minimal working example I actually get a different error. I put this into a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527063/cross-reference-to-section-title-containing-counter-and-umlaute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a 'by-pass', using a hack by writing a direct `\newlabel` command to the `.aux` file.

**This is tested for** `hyperref` **only and not meant to be portable at all!**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{UCcounter}
\setcounter{UCcounter}{0}

% Change to arabic counter format 
\renewcommand{\theUCcounter}{\arabic{UCcounter}}


\newcommand{\usecaseref}[1]{\emph{\nameref{#1}}}

% Change behaviour (except calling of \theUCcounter) etc. at will 
\newcommand{\usecaseprint}[1]{%
UC \theUCcounter: #1}%


\let\LaTeXStandardSection\section


\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{UCcounter}%
\LaTeXStandardSection{\usecaseprint{#1}}%    
% Bypass the normal label command with hyperrefs label style -- this uses the counter value at the
% moment the section is begun, not afterwards!
\immediate\write1{%  Directly write to aux - file -- I hope, this is portable
\string\newlabel{sec::uc::\theUCcounter}{{\thesection}{\thepage}{\usecaseprint{#1}}{section.\thesection}{}}}%
}%

\begin{document}



\section{First Use Case Name}

    This is the forwards reference: \usecaseref{sec::uc::5}

\section{Second Use Case Name}
    This is the backwards reference: \usecaseref{sec::uc::1}


\section{Third Use Case Name}
    This is the backwards reference: \usecaseref{sec::uc::2}

\newpage

\section{Fourth Use Case Name}%\label{sec:second}
    This is  yet another forward reference: \usecaseref{sec::uc::6}


\section{Fifth Use Case Name}%\label{sec:second}
    This is  yet another backwards reference: \usecaseref{sec::uc::3}

\section{Sixth Use Case Name}%\label{sec:second}
    This is  yet another backwards reference: \usecaseref{sec::uc::1}


\end{document}
```

I redefined the `\section` command, but it will only work with its default argument at the moment!

I also changed to automatic labelling for convenience purposes.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thx!

I refined Christian H.'s solution to be able to use normal sections as well. Therefore I created a new command instead of redefining the `\section` command. This command also takes as a second argument a labelname, so I can refer by a logical name instead of by number. Here's the final solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{UCcounter}
\setcounter{UCcounter}{0}

% Change to arabic counter format 
\renewcommand{\theUCcounter}{\arabic{UCcounter}}

\newcommand{\usecaseref}[1]{\emph{\nameref{#1}}}

% Change behaviour (except calling of \theUCcounter) etc. at will 
\newcommand{\usecaseprint}[1]{%
UC \theUCcounter: #1}%

% Define a new command for section titles with Use Cases
% First argument = Use Case Name; second argument = label
\newcommand{\UCsection}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{UCcounter}%
\section{\usecaseprint{#1}}%    
% Bypass the normal label command with hyperrefs label style -- this uses the counter value at the
% moment the section is begun, not afterwards!
\immediate\write1{%  Directly write to aux - file -- I hope, this is portable
\string\newlabel{uc:#2}{{\thesection}{\thepage}{\usecaseprint{#1}}{section.\thesection}{}}}%
}%

\begin{document}



\UCsection{First Use Case Name}{first}

    This is the forwards reference: \usecaseref{uc:fifth}

\UCsection{Second Use Case Name}{sec}
    This is the backwards reference: \usecaseref{uc:first}


\section{Normal Section}

\UCsection{Third Use Case Name}{third}
    This is the backwards reference: \usecaseref{uc:sec}

\newpage

\section{Another Normal Section}

\UCsection{Fourth Use Case Name}{fourth}
    This is  yet another forward reference: \usecaseref{uc:six}


\UCsection{Fifth Use Case Name}{fifth}
    This is  yet another backwards reference: \usecaseref{uc:third}

\section{Yet another normal section}

\UCsection{Sixth Use Case Name}{six}
    This is  yet another backwards reference: \usecaseref{uc:first}


\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]